# Ajax callback never called / triggered

Tags: commerce, ajax, payment-gateways

I'm working on a payment gateway, so I've created a BasePaymentOffsiteForm form where I'm trying to make an ajax callback, but it is not working.
Can you help me to know what is wrong with my code?

```
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['content'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="validate-phone-number">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $form['content']['mobile_phone'] = [
      '#type'   => 'textfield',
      '#title'  => $this->t('Mobile phone'),
    ];

    $form['content']['validate_client'] = [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => $this->t('Validate Client'),
      '#ajax' => [
        '#callback' => [get_class($this), 'clientValidateForm'],
        'event' => 'click',
        'wrapper' => 'validate-phone-number',
      ],
    ];

    $form['content']['cancel'] = [
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => $this->t('Cancel'),
      '#url' => Url::fromUri($form['#cancel_url']),
    ];


    return $form;
  }

  public static function clientValidateForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Pay',
    ];
    return $form['submit'];
  }
```

It never gets in cientValidateForm method.

Comment: You have to add any form elements in the form definition. They cannot be added in the ajax callback.

Answer (score 1):

You're never making it to your callback because you don't have your `#ajax` array defined correctly, `callback` should not be defined as a hashed key. Take a look at the [Adding an AJAX event example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms#s-adding-the-ajax-event) on d.o.

This should work:

```
$form['content']['validate_client'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('Validate Client'),
  '#ajax' => [
    // Change the callback key and update your callback value.
    'callback' => [$this, 'clientValidateForm'],
    'event' => 'click',
    'wrapper' => 'validate-phone-number',
  ],
];
```

Also note that Jaypan is right, you can't define new elements in your validation callback so you'll have to change that too. You may want to set a `$form_state` value in your validation handler and use that to add your element inside your build method. You may also need to update the wrapper value in your `#ajax` definition to align with the other changes.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, I just add the # in callback index just for testing, but the use of $this without get_class was the solution.

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to mark this answer is accepted if it solved your problem.